# How to specify the URL of a linked item in Semantic UI?

Tags: semantic-ui

When using a "Link Item", begun with `<div class="ui divided link items">`, in Semantic UI (as per the manual: http://semantic-ui.com/views/item.html), where should I specify the URL of the page I would like the item to link to?

I tried wrapping the whole `<div class="item">` within `<a>`, but doing so breaks the formatting of the item such that the content appears below the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sub your `div.item` with `a.item` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/sjv7eat4/) or HTML below:

```
<div class="ui divided link items">
  <a class="item" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="ui tiny image">
      <img src="http://www.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/stevie.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Google</div>
      <div class="description">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">
    <div class="ui tiny image">
      <img src="http://www.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/veronika.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Yahoo!</div>
      <div class="description">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="item" href="http://duckduckgo.com/" target="_blank">
    <div class="ui tiny image">
      <img src="http://www.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/jenny.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">DuckDuckGo</div>
      <div class="description">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is it - I was missing the `class="item"` on the `<a>` tag.